# Which document describes which application icon sizes are needed to submit an app?

Tags: iphone

It's crazy, but I can't find it. The HIG seems to talk only about system icons like "favorites", "search", etc.

Is there a special document that talks about this? Also, how must these icons be called and where must they be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)? It describes submission related things.

Answer (score 2):

I've only been able to kind of *distill* it from the HIG, but here's a blog post that's very helpful:

http://kgutteridge.co.uk/blog/2010/07/04/icon-sizes-filenames-for-ios-devices/

- iTunesArtwork – Icon for iTunes AdHoc distribution (512×512)
- Icon@2x.png – Home screen icon for iPhone 4 (114×114)
- Icon-72.png – Home screen icon for iPad (72×72)
- Icon-Small@2x.png – Settings/Spotlight icon for iPhone 4 (58×58)
- Icon.png – Home screen icon for iPhone 3 (57×57)
- Icon-Small-50.png – Spotlight icon for iPad (50×50)
- Icon-Small.png - Settings/Spotlight icon for iPhone 3 (29×29)

Might also check this out too for a bit more crucial info:

mrgan.tumblr.com/post/708404794/ios-app-icon-sizes

Answer (score 1):

This is detailed in Apple's [Technical Q&A QA1686: App Icons on iPad and iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1686.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is one of the first questions that comes up when searching for the necessary icon sizes for iOS Apps, and in the meantime, things have changed again with the appearance the new iPad ("3"), I'd like to add the currently relevant information here:

Apple has conveniently collected all the details about custom icons and images in one place now. Here goes: [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)